# How can the alternate bundle be used with the meter in quantikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, tikz-styles, quantikz

The `quantikz` package handles the `[alternate]` fine when it is placed before a normal gate.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{braket,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{quantikz}
        \ket{\psi}\;& \gate{I}\qwbundle[alternate]{}    &  \;\ket{\psi}\qwbundle[alternate]{}
    \end{quantikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But when the meter is used, it gives an error:

```
\begin{quantikz}
    \ket{\psi}\;& \meter\qwbundle[alternate]{}  &  \;\ket{\psi}\qwbundle[alternate]{}
\end{quantikz}
```

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/alternate' and I
> am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. I think the culprit
> is a tikzcd arrow in cell 1-2.

The problem is clearly the `[alternate]` option, since it works fine with the default bundle style.

```
\begin{quantikz}
    \ket{\psi}\;& \meter\qwbundle{} &  \;\ket{\psi}\qwbundle[alternate]{}
\end{quantikz}
```

[image]

How can `meter` be used with the `alternate` bundle style?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the `\meter` macro is as follows:

```
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\meter}{O{}{m}}{|[meter,label={[my label]#2},#1]| {} \qw}
```

Since this macro already puts `\qw` at the end, you cannot safely use another connection command afterwards. (It might work in certain cases, but since `\qw` is still added, the output won't be nice in most cases.) You can, however, make use of this defintion and write the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{quantikz}
    \ket{\psi}\;& |[meter]| \qwbundle[alternate]{} &  \;\ket{\psi}\qwbundle[alternate]{}
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]